# How to fix "During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: "

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, valueerror, try-except

How do i fix this error, whenever i enter data that should cause an exception more than once the program crashes. Here is my code and what it outputs, it should keep repeating until correct data is entered.

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgeFh.png)

```
flag=False

while flag==False:
    try:
        number=int(input("Enter number of books: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter number of books as a positive whole number ")
        number=int(input("Enter number of books: "))
    else:
        flag=True
```

[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Okxg4.png)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alex\OneDrive\Documents\ComputerScience\Intro2.py", line 5, in <module>
    number=int(input("Enter number of books: "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3.3'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alex\OneDrive\Documents\ComputerScience\Intro2.py", line 8, in <module>
number=int(input("Enter number of books: "))
```

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3.4'

Comment: To avoid that _specific_ error, don't raise another exception inside an `except`

Comment: Don't post images of code, error, data, etc.

Comment: @tripleee yes but how do i prevent it from crashing if a user raises an exception in the except?

Comment: @buran why shouldnt i post images?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow please post text, not images of text as it makes it easier for people to see and copy to evaluate.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it evaluates if your string is a digit, then breaks out of the look. Exception handling is expensive in computing terms and should be avoided where possible

```
while True:
    no_of_books = input("enter number of books")
    if no_of_books.isdigit():
        break
```

The reason your code didn't keep repeating was that it thew an exception on line 5 which was wrapped in the try block then in the except block it threw another exception on line 8 which was not wrapped in a try block so it terminated

**Updated in response to comment**, simply cast your string to an int like this then use `int_number_of_books` as the int

```
while True:
    no_of_books = input("enter number of books")
    if no_of_books.isdigit():
        int_number_of_books = int(no_of_books)
        break
if int_number_of_books > 0:
    # your code here
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to ensure that no_of_books is an integer as later on it refers to it as a string still.  Here is error message :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alex\OneDrive\Documents\ComputerScience\Intro2.py", line 7, in <module>
    while number <= 0:
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: I need to ensure that the value is an integer and does not contain decimals or negatives

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit of course you can use `if no_of_books.isdigit() and int(no_of_books) > 0:`  to ensure that the value is a positive integer and does not contain decimals